# Cannot scroll the ScrollView inside position absolute

Tags: react-native

I have code below. The content is displayed but not scrollable inside the Scrollview.

Someone expirences this before? Any help is really apprecieated.

What platform(s) does this occur on?
Android

SDK Version (managed workflow only)
No response

Environment
System:
OS: Windows 10 10.0.19041
Binaries:
Node: 14.16.1 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
npm: 6.14.12 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
IDEs:
Android Studio 4.1.3
Build #AI-201.8743.12.41.7199119, built on March 11, 2021
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
npmPackages:
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.0",
Devices:
Xiaomi Note 8 Pro

```
return (
      <View style={
         flex: 1,
         flexDirection: 'column',
         backgroundColor: 'black',
      }>
        Icon
      containerStyle={{
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 30,
        right: 15,
        zIndex: 2,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
      }}
      name="arrow-drop-up"
      size={35}
      onPress={() => this.setState({ isTextsVisible: false })}
    />
        <View style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          top: 30,
          left: 0,
          zIndex: 1,
          flex: 1,
        }}>
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{
            flexWrap: 'wrap',
            flexDirection: 'row',
            alignItems: 'flex-start',
            height: SCREEN_HEIGHT / 2,
          }}>
            {
              texts.map((text, i) => {
                this.tagRef[i] = null;
                return (
                  <View
                    key={i}
                    ref={c => this.tagRef[i] = c}
                  ><Tag
                      text={text.value}
                      onPress={() => this.onTextPress(text.value, i)}
                    /></View>
                )
              })
            }
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
      );
```

Comment: Did you try giving the `ScrollView` a prop of `style={{flex:1}}`? As opposed to the `contentContainerStyle`

Comment: thanks, i fixed it already, needs to set height for parent